# Prevent coding multiple if/else statements with two changing expressions

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, apex-code

I'm a beginner APEX developer (language based off of Java) and I was wondering if there is an efficient way to write conditional statements where two conditions change while the rest remains static.

For instance, in my code below, Countryy__c will change to say UK, US and Canada (besides France) and for each of these countries the Industry will change from Accounting to Medicine to Legal. Meanwhile, lead type and status will always remain as outbound and open respectively. Moreover each Country and Industry combination has a unique 'Owner ID'.

So in other words, there will be a total of 12 if/else statements with 12 different OwnerIds. Given that the code will be messy to maintain in the future if the number of countries and industries grow, is there a better way of coding this?

```
    public static void changeOwnerToQueue(List<String> DeactivatedUserIds){
    
    List<Lead> leadList = new List<Lead>();
    List<lead> updatedQueue = new List<Lead>();
    
    leadList = [SELECT Id, OwnerId, Countryy__c, Industry__c, Lead_Type__c, Status from lead 
    where OwnerId IN :DeactivatedUserIds];
    
    for(Lead l : leadList){
        
    if(l.Countryy__c == 'France' && l.Industry__c == 'Accounting' && l.Lead_Type__c == 'Outbound' && l.Status == 'Open'){
            
            l.OwnerId = '00G5J000000pX41';
            updatedQueue.add(l);      


   }
      }
```

Comment: In core java i would use a nested map `Map<String,Map<String,String>>` where keys of outer map are your countries and keys of your inner map are your industries mapping to your OwnerIds values.

Answer (score 0):

The most maintainable pattern for this kind of mapping in Apex is to use Custom Metadata. You'd create some Custom Metadata Type (`MyOwnerMap__mdt`), with fields for `Country__c`, `Industry__c`, and `Owner__c`. You'd create Custom Metadata records to represent all of your mappings. Then, in your code, you'd pull that data to create a Map, using a custom class as a key to represent the unique mapping of Country + Industry -> Owner:

```java
class OwnerMapKey {
    public String industry;
    public String country;

    public OwnerMapKey(String ind, String ctry) {
        this.industry = ind;
        this.country = ctry;
    }

    public Boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof OwnerMapKey) {
            OwnerMapKey o = (OwnerMapKey)other;

            return this.industry == o.industry && this.country == o.country;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Integer hashCode() {
        return (this.industry + this.country).hashCode();
    }
}


List<MyOwnerMap__mdt> ownerMapValues = MyOwnerMap__mdt.getAll().values();
Map<OwnerMapKey, Id> ownerMap = new Map<OwnerMapKey, Id>();

for (MyOwnerMap__mdt eachOwnerMap: ownerMapValues) {
    ownerMap.put(new OwnerMapKey(eachOwnerMap.Industry__c, eachOwnerMap.Country__c), eachOwnerMap.Owner__c);
}
```

Then, you can easily access the desired Owner value for any combination of Industry and Country. Note that you'll probably want to have a fallback if that entry is missing from your Custom Metadata.

```
someRecord.OwnerId = ownerMap.get(new OwnerMapKey(SOME_INDUSTRY, SOME_COUNTRY)) || defaultOwner;
```

(Disclaimer: above code written directly in Stack Overflow and untested).

The reason this pattern is valuable is that your solution then becomes admin-maintainable: you can change the mapping with no code changes and no deployment, just by altering the Custom Metadata records.